# Mouse click scrolling content instead of mouse wheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

How can we scroll the content left and right side while click on the content and hold the mouse click instead of mouse wheel in malihu mcustom scrollbar plugin?

I tried with lot of options. But no use

Answer (score 0):

Originally read this as you wanted to scroll the content left and right. Now I'm reading it as you want to use the left / right mouse buttons to scroll? In either case, you can do this with just javascript, no plugins.

You could use `mousedeown` to start a scrolling interval and sets which direction to scroll, then use `mouseup` clear the scrolling interval.

```js
let doc = document.scrollingElement,
    scroll = {
      distance: 200, //how far to scroll each interval
      interval: null,
      stop: function() { clearInterval(scroll.interval); },
      start: function(direction) {
        scroll.stop();
        scroll.interval = setInterval(function() {
          doc.scrollTo(doc.scrollLeft, doc.scrollTop + scroll.distance * direction);
        } , 200); //interval delay = scroll speed
      }
    };

document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //prevent right click menu
});

document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  scroll.start({ 1: 1, 2: -1 }[e.buttons] || 0); //1=left=down, 2=right=up
});

document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  scroll.stop();
});
```

```html
<div class="visual" style="height:0px;width:0px;border-left:100px solid transparent; border-right: 100px solid transparent;border-bottom: 2000px solid #eeeeee;margin-left:100px;"></div>
```